# MongoDB with node.js, I can not figure out how to sort group aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongodb-aggregation

I am using node.js to work with a mongodb. My query gives me the results I want, but I can't seem to sort it, at all, no matter what I try to sort it by.

Here's an example of a query

```
var query = function (db, callback) {
    var cursor = db.collection('collection').aggregate({
            $match: {
                "startdatetime": {
                    $gte: new Date([fromDate]),
                    $lte: new Date([toDate])
                }
            }
        },
        {$match: {"depth": {$gte: depthFrom, $lte: depthTo}}},
        {$unwind: "$dives"}, {$match: {"depth": {$gte: depthFrom, $lte: depthTo}}},
        {
            $group: {
                _id: {year: {$year: "$startdatetime"},depth: "depth"},
                average: {$avg: "$"+[parameter]}
            }
        }, {$sort: {year: 1,depth:1}});
    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if (doc != null) {
            console.log(doc);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    })
};
```

From this I get this result:

```
{ _id: { year: 2015, depth: 17.5 }, average: 7.809660041265659 }
{ _id: { year: 2015, depth: 16.5 }, average: 7.849712114661603 }
{ _id: { year: 2016, depth: 17.5 }, average: 7.402677186121112 }
{ _id: { year: 2016, depth: 16.5 }, average: 7.565136208888859 }
```

I would have liked a result like this (by year, then depth):

```
{ _id: { year: 2015, depth: 16.5 }, average: 7.849712114661603 }
{ _id: { year: 2015, depth: 17.5 }, average: 7.809660041265659 }
{ _id: { year: 2016, depth: 16.5 }, average: 7.565136208888859 }
{ _id: { year: 2016, depth: 17.5 }, average: 7.402677186121112 }
```

I have tried to sort by _id:1, year and depth, but no matter if I try them alone, or in combinations, nothing happens to the result.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post a sample document of your collection

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `year` and `depth` parameters are under `_id` object. So you should sort using:

```
{$sort: {'_id.year': 1, '_id.depth':1 }}
```

Or you can add a project phase before sorting and remove the `_id` nesting:

```
{$project: {_id: 0, year: '$_id.year', depth: '$_id.depth', average: 1 }}
```

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned that I have tried your first suggestion, but it does not work. Neither does your second suggestion. These two solutions to the problem is the ones I have found when searching for a solution, but no matter what I try to sort by, nothing changes...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It's a weird problem... I figured after playing around with `$project` that if `$project` was at the end of the query, it was ignored, so then I tried putting two `$sort` after each other. Turns out, what ever is last in my query is ignored. So now, the end of my query looks like this:

```
 {$sort:{year:-1}},{$sort:{year:-1}});
```

I don't know if this is a special case for me, or if it is a "normal" bug, but hope I might save others from the frustration I've had.